# How can I connect to a MariaDB (MySQL) instance on localhost?

Tags: mysql, linux, authentication, connection, mariadb

I am installing FrontAccounting with MariaDB (rather than MySQL) just for my own personal use, accessing it via browser on `http://localhost/frontaccounts`. But attempts to log in as `root` to set up the database don't work: *Cannot connect to database. User or password is invalid ...* . Similar error messages occur when trying to log on as `root` in phpMyAdmin, SQLbuddy, MySQL Workbench, etc.

(In fact, this problem can also occur with MySQL, so you can substitute 'MySQL' wherever 'MariaDB' appears in what follows.)

The problem is that I am trying to log on as `root` from my computer's IP address (`root@MYCOMPUTER`), externally visible to the internet, to a server running on a "different" IP address (127.0.0.1, localhost) which requires `root@localhost` -- even though it is the same computer!

How to fix this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

The following answer that I eventually found will allow you to create a user at one IP address to access the MariaDB (MySQL) server at another address, even if that address is `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`.

In a terminal window, type:

```
$ sudo mysql -u root -p -h localhost
```

Type your password:

```
[sudo] password for YOURUSERNAME:
```

Type the MariaDB `root` password, or press Enter (for default blank password):

```
Enter password:
```

The MariaDB Monitor welcome banner appears ...

```
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 39
Server version: 10.0.28-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Ubuntu 16.04
Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

... and the monitor command prompt waits for your input (`none` means you are not connected to any database yet):

```
MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Create a user at `localhost` that MariaDB *will* accept, and quit:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE USER 'root'@'%';
     -> \q;
Bye
~$
```

This allows you to at least connect, and is a model for allowing other users to connect. These minimal instructions leave security holes so, after you have created users on MariaDB, given them passwords (don't forget `root`), and granted privileges and roles, these holes will be closed.

For additional security, specify the IP address of the users' machines, e.g. `'root'@'localhost'` instead of `'root'@'%'`.